# Mean squared absolute value of inner product of unit vectors

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, hilbert-spaces, inner-product

Given a nonempty finite subset $S$ of the unit sphere of $d$-dimensional complex Hilbert space, let $\lambda(S) = \frac{1}{\lvert S \rvert^2} \sum_{x,y \in S} \lvert \langle x,y \rangle \rvert^2$ be the mean squared absolute value of the inner product of two vectors chosen from $S$.

A basic observation from experiment is that $\lambda(S) \geq \frac1d$. This looks simple enough, but I don't know how to prove it, and as I've had no answers on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573359/average-squared-absolute-value-of-inner-product-between-some-unit-vectors-in-a-h) I am asking the question here.

A second experimental observation is that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are disjoint then $\lambda(S_1 \cup S_2) \leq \max(\lambda(S_1), \lambda(S_2))$.

If these conjectures are true, it follows that $\mathcal{E}_d = \{S: \lambda(S) = \frac1d\}$ is closed under disjoint unions, and it would be interesting to characterize its "basic" sets, i.e. those sets in $\mathcal{E}_d$ that are not a disjoint union of other sets in $\mathcal{E}_d$ (or alternatively, those with no proper subset in $\mathcal{E}_d$). Clearly these include the orthonormal bases, but there are plenty of others, e.g. $S = \{(1, 0), (\frac12, \frac{\sqrt3}{2}), (\frac12, -\frac{\sqrt3}{2})\}$ for $d = 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Welch bound gives

$$\lambda(S) = \frac{1}{\lvert S \rvert^2}
 \sum_{x,y \in S} \lvert \langle x,y \rangle \rvert^2 \geq 
\frac{(\sum_{x \in S} \lvert \langle x,x \rangle \rvert)^2}{d \lvert S \rvert^2}=\frac{1}{d}$$ 
which is what you want.

There are Welch bound equality sets (do a google search) but achieving equality for general set size $|S|$ is difficult.

Comment: Thank you, that was the reference I needed!